# Moving a sprite using event commands

Tags: python, events, pygame

I'm trying to blit an image as a background, and then have a sprite moving in all directions and rotate.  So far, I have the following:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

BGimageName = 'joker.jpg'
FGimageName = 'bmanicon.tga'

pygame.init()

DisWidth  = 900
DisHeight = 600

x = -500
y = -300

spriteROT = 1.0
SPHpos = (DisWidth//2, DisHeight//2)
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((DisWidth, DisHeight), 0, 32)
BGimage = pygame.image.load(BGimageName).convert()
FGimage = pygame.image.load(FGimageName).convert_alpha()

def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    move_x = -1
                elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    move_x = +1
                elif event.key == K_UP:
                    move_y = -1
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    move_y = +1
                elif event.key == K_r:
                    rotationDIR = + 1.0
                elif event.key == K_w:
                    rotationDIR = - 1.0
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    move_x = 0
                elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    move_x = 0
                elif event.key == K_UP:
                    move_y = 0
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    move_y = 0
                elif event.key == K_r:
                    rotationDIR = 0
                elif event.key == K_w:
                    rotationDIR = 0

        DISPLAYSURF.blit(BGimage, (x, y))

        RotSPH = pygame.transform.rotate(FGimage, spriteROT)
        w, h = RotSPH.get_size()
        spriteDrawPos = (SPHpos[0] - w // 2, SPHpos[1] - h // 2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(RotSPH, spriteDrawPos)

        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

This is all pretty new to me.  Most of it was provided by our professor, and we then had to figure out the rest and personalize it.  Unfortunately I wasn't present the day of class where we discussed events, so I don't really understand them.  I think that I currently have everything working because the background and the sprite both display, but the sprite doesn't move when I press any buttons.  How can I get Python to recognize that I want the sprite to move?

I tried to put `FGimage.move_x` and such in the event keys, i.e.

```
if event.key == K_LEFT:
    FGimage.move_x = -1
```

but that doesn't work, giving me the error

```
Attribute Error: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'move_x'
```

I think I'm close, but I'm still missing the last step.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not moving the sprite is because you are not changing any variables with the events.

Specifically the location variable `spriteDrawPos` is not changing because the line `spriteDrawPos = (SPHpos[0] - w // 2, SPHpos[1] - h // 2)`  which modifies it is not changing because `SPHpos` is never going to change because `spriteROT` never changes.

To fix this modify the code to work with the variables you changed in the event.

```
spriteROT += rotationDIR
RotSPH = pygame.transform.rotate(FGimage, spriteROT)
w, h = RotSPH.get_size()
spriteDrawPos = (SPHpos[0] - w // 2 + move_x, SPHpos[1] - h // 2 + move_y)
DISPLAYSURF.blit(RotSPH, spriteDrawPos)
```

This will hopefully allow your sprite to move, but probably too fast.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I thought it looked a bit weird, and wasnt entirely sure how to add in the variable that was supposed to be adjusting. Thanks a ton!